# How does the "setcookie" function work in php?

Tags: php

I am in confused about what will happen if I write code to set a cookie using the `setcookie()` function. How does the browser come to known that it needs to create cookie file?

Can I access the *var* of cookies just below the line where I set cookie like below code?

```
setcookie("TestCookie", 'test', time()+3600);  
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Please explain to me how cookies files are created, and how session cookies created when we call `session_start()`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

Cookie are created on the client machine. They have to be sent before any HTML output, because they are sent with the header. If you want to work with `sessions` then you have to use the `superglobal` `$_SESSION`.

If you want to create a cookie:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', 'exipiration', 'path where is valid ('/' for all)', 'domain')
```

Once you reload the page the cookie is avaible, and you can call it using the superglobal:

```
$_COOKIE['name'];
```

If you want to call a cookie before the page reloads, then you can implement a solution with JavaScript. You can create a cookie with a JS function, and call it with another function, without refreshing the page

Comment: That's a very confusing accumulation of random information which doesn't really answer the question.